# Why does my averaging function return NaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I created a class `Car` and add objects of that class (car1, car2, car3) to an array:

```
class Car{
    constructor(prise){  
        this.prise = prise;
    }
};
```

I also declared a function that should determine the average price of objects in the array:

```
function averageСost(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        total = ( total + arr[i] ) / arr.length;;
    }
    return total;
};

var car1 = new Car( 10000 );
var car2 = new Car( 20000 );
var car3 = new Car( 30000 );
var cars = [ car1, car2, car3 ];  

console.log( averageСost( cars ) );
```

Comment: Why is there no reference to `prise` in your second code block?

Comment: `total + arr[i]` ==> `total + arr[i].prise`

Comment: `total + arr[i]` is meaningless because `arr[i]` is a `Car` and not a `Number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do omething like this:

```js
class Car{
    constructor(prise){  
        this.prise = prise;
    }
};

let array = [];
array.push(new Car(1));
array.push(new Car(2));
array.push(new Car(3));

let avg = 0;

if (array.length > 0) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach((car) => sum += car.prise);
  avg = sum / array.length;
}

console.log(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't add `Car` objects (which you are doing with `total + arr[i]`). You need to add the `prise` property of those objects.

Also, your averaging logic is wrong; you're dividing by the array length after every addition, which is going to give you an incorrect result. Your function should be:

```
function averageСost(arr) {
    var total = 0,
        i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total = total + arr[i].prise;
    }
    return total / arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a car object to another car object, whereas you want to add the ***price*** of each car together.

```
function averageСost(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total = (total + arr[i].prise) / arr.length;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Also, please fix the spelling of price, cus it feelsbadman

Answer (score 0):

change your averageCost function to

```
function averageСost(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        total = total + arr[i].prise;
    }
    total = total / arr.length;
    return total;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling an object instead of the number inside of the Car class when calculating the total.

In this line:

```
total = ( total + arr[i] ) / arr.length;
```

Should be:

```
total = ( total + arr[i].prise ) / arr.length;
```